# A custom shape line between two container that change color like progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Based on the image above, what I'm trying to achieve are:

1. Once the container reach middle of the viewport, it's text background will change to yellow.
2. And also while user scroll down or up, the middle arrow will slowly fill in with yellow color until the user reach the middle viewport of the next container.

Now, I manage to make the focus container to change its text background to yellow and also I already display the progress bar shape but I've no idea **how to make it change to yellow in relative on the user scroll action (like progress bar). Plus, the first progress bar need to start from right while the second one will start with left and vice versa for the next one.**

P/S : I'm thinking of just using image, but then for sure making it to change to yellow like a progress bar is impossible.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height(),
        topLimit = winHeight * .2;

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        $('.parent').each(function() {
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if (thisTop <= topLimit) {
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('highlight');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 250px;
}

.img-col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green; 
  float:left;
}

.text-col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue; 
  float: right;
}

.highlight .text-col {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.middle-line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.vertical-right {
  height: 20px;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.vertical-left {
  height: 20px;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.vertical-right-bottom {
  height: 20px;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.vertical-left-top {
  height: 20px;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="img-col"></div>
    <div class="text-col">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="middle-line">
  <div class="vertical-right"></div>
  <div class="vertical-left"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="text-col" style="float: left;">Some text here</div>
    <div class="img-col" style="float: right;"></div>
</div>

<div class="middle-line">
  <div class="vertical-right-bottom"></div>
  <div class="vertical-left-top"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="img-col"></div>
    <div class="text-col">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="middle-line">
  <div class="vertical-right"></div>
  <div class="vertical-left"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="text-col" style="float: left;">Some text here</div>
    <div class="img-col" style="float: right;"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you found this image? If it's a webpage, you could probably just inspect the page to see how it's done and if it's simply using an image.

Comment: @Kevin Pastor it's not from any webpage. This image is from my designer friend.

Comment: @NazrinNoorzan, You could use the image like a mask in a sense. With a yellow fixed DIV behind, as the user scrolls up or down, the mask would allow the yellow to show through from behind. It can cover 50% of the height of the window, and only fill part of the masking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Text Background Change

To change the text background when it reaches the centre of the viewport is relatively simple and can be accomplished with some thoughtfully constructed CSS classes and a little JavaScript.

Each item in the main list has several components, including several text boxes that need their background colour altered. To each of those text boxes we add a class - let's call it `.colour-animate`. In our CSS we add a `transition` attribute to make the animation fade smoothly.

```
.colour-animate {
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
```

Now the JavaScript.

If each item in your main list has the class name `.item` we can iterate through the list of `item`s and check if each one is above the viewport's centre. This is a simple calculation:

```
if ( items[ i ].getBoundingClientRect().top < ( window.innerHeight / 2 ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

If so then we then iterate through the `.colour-animate` children of that `item`. For each `.colour-animate` we can change the background colour. For each `.item` that is below the viewport centre we reset the background colours of its `.colour-animate` children. This means that the yellow resets if we scroll back up the page.

Complete code for the background change:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName( "item" );

function scroll() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
        var colours = items[ i ].getElementsByClassName( "colour-animate" );
        if ( items[ i ].getBoundingClientRect().top < ( window.innerHeight / 2 ) ) {
          for ( var j = 0; j < colours.length; j++ ) {
            colours[ j ].style.backgroundColor = "rgba( 255,208,0,0.7 )";
           }
        } else {
           for ( var j = 0; j < colours.length; j++ ) {
            colours[ j ].style.backgroundColor = "";
           }
        }
    }
}


window.onscroll = function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll); 
} 
window.onload = scroll();
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
    background-color: #111;
    padding: 50px;
}
.item {
    background-image: url( https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f7/Leger_railway_crossing.jpg );
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
.item.right {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.item .description {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.7);
}
.item .header {
    font-size: 150%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
.item .header.left {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
}
.colour-animate {
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="header colour-animate">Title 1</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item right">
    <div class="header colour-animate left">Title 2</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="header colour-animate">Title 3</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item right">
    <div class="header colour-animate left">Title 4</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="header colour-animate">Title 5</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Animating the Arrow Divider

Animating the arrow graphic as you scroll is quite an interesting problem. It is probably best solved with CSS SVG.

You would first draw the arrow as a SVG vector. You can do this in a vector editor, or since it's quite a simple graphic, it's probably easier to do it manually. Your SVG code will look something like:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" />
</svg>
```

It's very important that you draw it only using paths, as above.

Now to animate the yellow as you scroll, you need to draw a second path that is identical to the first, except it's yellow. And add a new class name to it - let's say you use `.scroll-animate`. Your complete SVG might look like:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
     <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" />
     <path fill="none" stroke="#ffd000" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" class="scroll-animate" />
</svg>
```

There's a brilliant little article over at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) that explains how to animate a SVG path. Basically you find the length of the path using `.getTotalLength()`, and make your `.scroll-animate` paths have a stroke dash length equal to that length. This means you can slide path in from start to finish by animating its stroke offset from that length to 0. To attach this to the scrolling, we make the stroke offset equal to the path's length times the scroll position of the path within the viewport, divided by the viewport height.

```
var paths = document.getElementsByClassName( "scroll-animate" ),
    length = paths[ 0 ].getTotalLength();

function scroll() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++ ) {
        paths[ i ].style.strokeDashoffset = length * ( paths[ i ].getBoundingClientRect().top / window.innerHeight );
    }
}

window.onscroll = function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll); 
}
```

Not only does this animate the yellow arrow as you scroll down, but it reverses it as you scroll up.

### Result

The complete code (or you can view a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jla-/pen/pqPbGG) of it):

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName( "item" ),
    paths = document.getElementsByClassName( "scroll-animate" ),
    length = paths[ 0 ].getTotalLength();

for ( var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++ ) {
    paths[ i ].style.strokeDasharray = length;
    paths[ i ].style.strokeDashoffset = length;
}

function scroll() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
        var colours = items[ i ].getElementsByClassName( "colour-animate" );
        if ( items[ i ].getBoundingClientRect().top < ( window.innerHeight / 2 ) ) {
          for ( var j = 0; j < colours.length; j++ ) {
            colours[ j ].style.backgroundColor = "rgba( 255,208,0,0.7 )";
           }
        } else {
           for ( var j = 0; j < colours.length; j++ ) {
            colours[ j ].style.backgroundColor = "";
           }
        }
    }
    
    for ( var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++ ) {
        paths[ i ].style.strokeDashoffset = length * ( paths[ i ].getBoundingClientRect().top / window.innerHeight );
    }
}


window.onscroll = function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll); 
} 
window.onload = scroll();
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
    background-color: #111;
    padding: 50px;
}
.item {
    background-image: url( https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f7/Leger_railway_crossing.jpg );
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.item.right {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.item .description {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.7);
}
.item .header {
    font-size: 150%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
.item .header.left {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
}
.colour-animate {
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="header colour-animate">Title 1</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<svg width="100%" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" />
    <path fill="none" stroke="#ffd000" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" class="scroll-animate" />
</svg>

<div class="item right">
    <div class="header colour-animate left">Title 2</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<svg width="100%" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" />
    <path fill="none" stroke="#ffd000" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" class="scroll-animate" />
</svg>

<div class="item">
    <div class="header colour-animate">Title 3</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<svg width="100%" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" />
    <path fill="none" stroke="#ffd000" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" class="scroll-animate" />
</svg>

<div class="item right">
    <div class="header colour-animate left">Title 4</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<svg width="100%" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <path fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" />
    <path fill="none" stroke="#ffd000" stroke-width="2" d="M01000 0 L1000 50 L500 50 L 510 30 L510 70 L500 50 L 0 50 L0 100" class="scroll-animate" />
</svg>

<div class="item">
    <div class="header colour-animate">Title 5</div>
    <div class="description colour-animate">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet ante malesuada, aliquam libero sit amet, varius lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a lot of ways to do this. Images with transparent portions. Smart CSS usage with border colors or with simple margins. I am not sure what would be best since we're not working with the actual code, but more of a mock up at this point.

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var winHeight = $(window).height(),
    topLimit = winHeight * .2;

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.parent').each(function() {
      var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
      if (thisTop <= topLimit) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
      }
    });
    $(".line-wrap").each(function() {
      var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
      if (thisTop <= topLimit) {
        if ($(".mid-line", this).hasClass("top-right")) {
          $(this).css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,0,0), rgba(255,255,0,1))");
        } else {
          $(this).css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,0,0), rgba(255,255,0,1))");
        }
      } else {
        $(this).css("background-image", "");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.parent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: black;
}

.img-col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}

.text-col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}

.highlight .text-col {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.line-wrap {
  /* Line Color */
  background: #FFF;
}

.mid-line {
  /* Spacing and Borders */
  height: 19px;
  width: calc(100% - 1px);
  background: black;
  border: 0;
}

.top-right {
  /* Verticals Sides */
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.top-left {
  /* Verticals Sides */
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.bottom-left {
  margin-left: 1px;
}

.bottom-right {
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="img-col"></div>
    <div class="text-col">Some text here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="line-wrap">
    <div class="mid-line top-right">
    </div>
    <div class="mid-line bottom-left">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="text-col" style="float: left;">Some text here</div>
    <div class="img-col" style="float: right;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="line-wrap">
    <div class="mid-line top-left">
    </div>
    <div class="mid-line bottom-right">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="img-col"></div>
    <div class="text-col">Some text here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="line-wrap">
    <div class="mid-line top-right">
    </div>
    <div class="mid-line bottom-left">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="text-col" style="float: left;">Some text here</div>
    <div class="img-col" style="float: right;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent"></div>
</div>
```

Using the same progress code, you can just color a different background. I thought a bit of CSS flair might be nice, hence the transparent gradient background. If you wanted to make more steps and have the gradient change or grow, you'd just need to slice up the scroll action more.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height(),
        topLimit = winHeight * .2;

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        $('.parent').each(function() {
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if (thisTop <= topLimit) {
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
                $(this).next('.middle-line').addClass('is-active');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('highlight');
                $(this).next('.middle-line').removeClass('is-active');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 250px;
}

.img-col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green; 
  float:left;
}

.text-col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue; 
  float: right;
}

.highlight .text-col {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.middle-line.is-active::before,
.middle-line.is-active::after {
  width: 50%;
}

.middle-line.is-active .vertical-bottom,
.middle-line.is-active .vertical-top {
  height: 20px;
}

.middle-line.is-active::before {
  transition: width 0.2s 0.2s ease-in;
}

.middle-line.is-active::after {
  transition: width 0.2s 0.4s ease-out;
}

.middle-line.is-active .vertical-bottom {
  transition: height 0.2s 0.6s ease-out;
}

.middle-line.is-active .vertical-top {
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in;
}

.middle-line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.middle-line::before,
.middle-line::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
}

.middle-line::before {
  transition: width 0.2s 0.4s ease-out;
  right: 0;
}

.middle-line::after {
  transition: width 0.2s 0.2s ease-in;

  right: 50%;
}

.middle-line.alternate::before {
  left: 0;
}

.middle-line.alternate::after {
  left: 50%;
}

.middle-line.alternate .vertical-top {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}

.middle-line.alternate .vertical-bottom {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.vertical-top {
  transition: height 0.2s 0.6s ease-out;
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.vertical-bottom {
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in;
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="img-col"></div>
    <div class="text-col">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="middle-line">
  <div class="vertical-top"></div>
  <div class="vertical-bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="text-col" style="float: left;">Some text here</div>
    <div class="img-col" style="float: right;"></div>
</div>

<div class="middle-line alternate">
  <div class="vertical-top"></div>
  <div class="vertical-bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="img-col"></div>
    <div class="text-col">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="middle-line">
  <div class="vertical-top"></div>
  <div class="vertical-bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="text-col" style="float: left;">Some text here</div>
    <div class="img-col" style="float: right;"></div>
</div>

<div class="middle-line alternate">
    <div class="vertical-top"></div>
    <div class="vertical-bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've edited your markup and manage animations via css instead.